# Count Down Random Numbers to 0 within given time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, countdown

I'm creating a countdown, which i need to count down it to 0 but in random numbers.

Ex- countdown from 4 minutes by second by second, but i need to show a value between 300 to 390 countdown to 0 with random numbers within above 4 minutes period.

I created random number count down, but still cannot able to figure out how to target that become 0 within given time.

```
<script>
var count = 350; //this is a random value between(300-390)
var timer = setInterval(function() {
//this will generate number between 0 to 10 and reduce it from count randimly
    count -= Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    //set it to html element
    jQuery('#maindvpart').html(count);

//when number become 0
    if( count <= 0) {
        jQuery('#maindvpart').html(0);
        count = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }

//but i need to run this countdown within 4 minutes
//(so when 0 minutes ends above count should zero, until 0 it should count down from random number)

},1000);
</script>
<div id="maindvpart">&nbsp;</div>
```

anyone have idea or example how to do this, thank you

Comment: Didn't get your point " but in random numbers. ".. generally a count down begins with 1 - 10 or 10 - 1.. means 10..9..8..7..6 or 6..7..8..9..10 why are you want that random count ?

Comment: You mean to say when clock hits 4 mins, the `count` variable should reset to 0?

Comment: @palaѕн exactly, i have another countdown which count lets say 4 minutes to 0 (actually that time also vary ) when it hit zero i want above countdown also be 0, in between i need to show countdown above one randomly,

Comment: Ok, you can simply check how much time has elapsed since the timer started and if it is > 4, just reset the count.

Answer (score 2):

Your `"timer"` runs each second.  When you do `"count -= Math.floor(Math.random()*9);"`, it reduces "count" variable value much faster, so you will always reach `"count <= 0"` much faster than 4 minutes.  If you want to run your timer for 4 minutes, you need to run your timer per second - 240 times, and "display a random number", but do not subtract that random number from count.  Does this help?

Editing with an example, hoping it would point you towards your goal:

```
<script>
var count = 240; //4 minutes
var displayNumber = 350; //or whatever number you want to start with
var timer = setInterval(function() {
    //this will generate number between 0 to 10 and reduce it from displayNumber randomly
    displayNumber -= Math.floor(Math.random()*9);
    count--;
    console.log(displayNumber);

    // exit if either the display number is <= 0 or the time is up
    if( displayNumber <= 0 || count <= 0) {
        console.log(0);
        displayNumber = 0;
        clearInterval(timer);
    }
},1000);
</script>
```

Comment: the way is correct but problem is subtract, ex- if i subtract random numbers from 350 at the end it also not near 0 or less than 0, i'm finding a way to countdown it to near 0, lets say 8 or 15 also ok,

Comment: What if you used two numbers?  1 is count, that can start around 240.  2nd can be a number starting from 350, and you can subtract a random number from that second number for your display.  Then you can stop timer when either of them reaches <= 0.  I will write up a sample and edit the answer. Give me a couple minutes.

Comment: thank you but i have to stay on time frame, and do the random do the countdown to a seperate number :) becoz that time frame use for run some other functions like progress bar

Comment: Would you be able to give whole example then? Without seeing complete picture, this is only a guess from me :)

Answer (score 1):

Solution 1:

simply modify the time interval after which the random number is reduced by unit step (ie:1) to indicate the time step necessary for the random number to equal 0 when the time is up . the equation would be :
{delay before subtracting 1 from rand# (in sec) = time elapsed till rand# reaches 0 (in sec)/rand#}

ex:

1) rand# = 300 , needed to count down till reaches 0 in  2 minutes (120sec) , then 300 needs to count down by 1 each 120/300 sec

```
var count = 300 // your randomly generated number; 
var time = 60 //time elapsed before the random number to equal 0;
var timer = setInterval(function() {
count = count -1;
console.log(count);
if( count <= 0) {
    count = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
    }
},(time/count)*1000);
```

Solution 2:

modify the unit step by which the random number is decreased every second till it reaches 0 after the specified time is elapsed . the equation would be :
{random # decrement step = rand#/time elapsed till rand# reaches 0 (in sec)}

ex:

1) rand# = 300 , needed to count down till reaches 0 in  1 minute (60sec) , then 300 needs to count down by 300/60 each 1 sec

```
var count = 300 // your randomly generated number; 
var time = 20 //time elapsed before the random number to equal 0;
var decrementStep=count/time; 

var timer = setInterval(function() {
count = count - decrementStep;
console.log(count);
if( count <= 0) {
    count = 0;
    clearInterval(timer);
    }
},1000);
```

Comment: is there have some example for this external link also ok, thank you :)

Comment: modified the answer to contain sample code , hope it helps :)

Comment: kindly consider marking the answer as accepted if it qualifies as such , if it doesn't and you need further help please ask about what you need in a comment , thank you